# Change jQuery $ function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the accessibility parameter of jQuery which is $
usually for access the jQuery we use.

```
$.document....Bla.Bla...
```

but i want to access this $ variable something like this

```
NI.$.document......
```

Help me to solve this problem.

But i don't want to use something like this..

```
var my_Js=$.noConflict(true);
```

Comment: why dont you want to use `var my_Js=$.noConflict(true);`

Comment: Why not `NI.$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);`?

Comment: `But i don't want to use something like this` - why not?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
(function(my_Js){

    my_Js(function(){

       alert('my_Js is safe!');

    });

})(jQuery)
```

Comment: jQuery scope which has a global reference using the 'jQuery' variable and passing the reference to a function to override the reference without using the noConflict.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `jQuery.noConflict(true);` and then assign that to the object that you want to use

```
var NI$ = $.noConflict(true);

NI$(document).ready(function(){})
```

```js
var NI$ = $.noConflict(true);

NI$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('HEllo');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">Hello</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to use this {var NI$ = $.noConflict(true);}

Comment: Any specific reason that you dont want to use this and yet change $ to NI$

Comment: Yes there is a reason @Shubham Khatri.

Comment: Is there is a way to make wrapper for jQuery